# GPS stuck to a single source

Tags: c#, .net, gps

We are developing a tracking application using VS 2012 Windows application targeting windows 8.1.

We are using the GeoCoordinateWatcher Class. For some reason it seems that if the first fix is from a wifi and you then turn off the wifi, the application can't get a satellite fix ( the watcher state keeps returning no data). It can only see the wifi location.

Same issue seems to appear if the first fix is from a GPS satellite.

Not sure if this is a hardware or a software issue... But I need the watcher to use both sources based on availability.

Appreciate any insight on this issue.

Following is the part of the code responsible to capture the GPS. Its called on a timer that works every XX.

```
private string SendingData()
    {
        try
        {

            DataXML = "";
            string result = "";
            Write_Trace_File("SendingData: Watcher Status: " + watcher.Status.ToString());
            if (watcher.Status != GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
            {
                try
                {
                    watcher.TryStart(true,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    Write_Trace_File(exp.Message);
                }
            }
            string cur_long = "";
            string cur_lat = "";
            string cur_speed = "";
            if (watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
            {
                Write_Trace_File("SendingData: GPS not captured yet.");
                if (currlatitude.ToString() != "0.0" && currlatitude.ToString() != "" && currlatitude.ToString() != "0")
                {
                    Write_Trace_File("SendingData:Using Cached GPS.GPS last captured at" + lastPosDate);
                    cur_long = currlongtitude.ToString();
                    cur_lat = currlatitude.ToString();
                    if (speed.ToString() != "0")
                    {
                        cur_speed = speed.ToString();
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    Write_Trace_File("SendingData:No Cached GPS.");
                    return "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Write_Trace_File("SendingData:Using Captured GPS.");
                cur_long = watcher.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString();
                cur_lat = watcher.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString();
                cur_speed = watcher.Position.Location.Speed.ToString();
            }


    }
```

Comment: this is a really broad question do have any code for this?

Comment: Just added the part of the code responsible to obtain the GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher.Close()
```

and

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher.Start()
```

methods to see if this kicks it back into life?

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes I did but to no avail. I actually have to enable/disable the whole windows location driver for it to switch sources, or close and reopen the application. I tried instantiating a new watcher if old watcher status is No Data but that didn't work either.